# Subtract two field from previous field in dynamic report

Tags: jasper-reports

in jasper-report :i am trying to sum first (Balance) field with second (Amount)field ,then Subtract the result from second (Balance) field.
can anyone help me ?

Like the image:

[image: like the image]

how can i get previous (Balance) field every time

Answer (score 0):

After some research I've found this: [Getting a previous record's value (for calculation in variables, etc)](https://community.jaspersoft.com/wiki/getting-previous-records-value-calculation-variables-etc)

Quoting from that article:

> Variables are incremented in the order they are declared, so you can exploit this order to keep track of the "previous" records value.
>   You need two report variables: one to hold the current value and the  other to hold the previous value. The trick is to declare the "previous value" variable prior to the "current value" variable and make the first copy the value of the second  like this:

```
<variable name="INITIAL" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Report" calculation="Nothing">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{AAA}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>

<variable name="AAA" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Report" calculation="Nothing">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{FieldA}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

> Of course if you are creating a calculation for comparison, then you need a third variable to calculate the difference between the two:

```
<variable name="DELTA" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Report" calculation="Nothing">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{AAA}-$V{INITIAL}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```

From what I understand what you want to do is: something = balance2 - (balance1 + amount2).

Following should work for you:

```
<variable name="PREVIOUS" class="java.math.BigDecimal" resetType="Report" calculation="Nothing">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$V{CURRENT}]]></variableExpression>
    <initialValueExpression><![CDATA[new BigDecimal(0)]]></initialValueExpression>
</variable>

<variable name="CURRENT" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Report" calculation="Nothing">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{BALANCE}]]></variableExpression>
</variable>

<variable name="SOMETHING" class="java.lang.Integer" resetType="Report" calculation="Nothing">
    <variableExpression><![CDATA[$F{BALANCE}-($V{PREVIOUS}+$F{AMOUNT})]]></variableExpression>
</variable>
```